# update NSLayoutConstaint of a view with UIPanGesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIView` and i add many `UIImageView`s (example 5, the number is dynamic) as subviews.
all UIImageViews are added with `NSLayoutConstraint`(sizeToFit and center related to superView center). All center related constraints are added to the `UIView`(parent view).

each `UIImageView` has a panGesture. so when i move a `UIImageView`, have to update the center related constraint of that `UIImageView`.

Question is,

**How to identify the constraints of the moving `UIImageView`?**

(do i need to keep the reference of all created constraints? or is there any other way to do this?)

**Edit:My workaround**

Thanks @Lord Zsolt for the answer. 
I wrote the below code(solution to my problem). it may help to others who has the same problem.

define as globale variables

```
NSLayoutConstraint *selectedImageViewCenterXconstraint, *selectedImageViewCenterYconstraint;
```

then the UIPanGestureRecognizer selector method is:

```
-(void)moveImageView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    UIImageView *senderView = (UIImageView*)recognizer.view;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        selectedImageViewCenterXconstraint = nil;
        selectedImageViewCenterYconstraint = nil;
        NSArray *viewConstraints = self.view.constraints;
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in viewConstraints) {
            if ([constraint.firstItem isEqual:senderView]) {
                if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeCenterX) {
                    NSLog(@"gotCenterX");
                    selectedImageViewCenterXconstraint = constraint;
                }else if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeCenterY) {
                    NSLog(@"gotCenterY");
                    selectedImageViewCenterYconstraint = constraint;
                }
            }

            if (selectedImageViewCenterXconstraint && selectedImageViewCenterYconstraint) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:senderView.superview];

    CGFloat newXconst,newYconst;
    newXconst = selectedImageViewCenterXconstraint.constant + translation.x;
    newYconst = selectedImageViewCenterYconstraint.constant + translation.y;

    selectedImageViewCenterXconstraint.constant = newXconst;
    selectedImageViewCenterYconstraint.constant = newYconst;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:senderView.superview];
}
```

Comment: Creating properties for the constraints you want to animate/have a reference to is perfectly acceptable, not just a workaround. This code looks totally fine assuming you get the result u want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIView subclasses have a property `constraints` which gives you an `NSArray` containing the constraints added onto that view.

You can search for your constraint in that array and verify it either `firstItem` or `lastItem` is your `UIImageView`.

Code sample:

```
//Assuming self is a view controller.
NSArray *constraints = [self.view constraints];
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in constraints) {
    if (constraint.firstItem == myImageView ||
        constraint.secondItem == myImageView) {
        NSLog(@"Constraint belongs to myImageView");
    }
}
```